# Modal form SetFocus not selecting control

Tags: ms-access, vba

**Objective:** Show a programmatic modal form with the appropriate control initially selected and ready for user input or interaction.

**Code:**

```
Dim frm As Form

Set frm = New Form_Popup_Sign

With frm
    'Show window and SetFocus appropriately
    .Visible = True
    !CommandCancel.SetFocus

    '.Modal = False: .Modal = True

    'Loop until response (change in form.visible state) is received on popup
    'User clicking Cancel or Sign sets .Visible = False
    Do While .Visible
        Sleep 1 'Sleeping makes CPU effect negligible
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Return popup_sign handle and leave form open to expose results
    load_Popup_Sign = frm.hWnd
End With
' Form is destroyed later
```

**Results:**

- The target control's GotFocus event DOES fire.
- The form appears but appears to have nothing focused (selected).

  - In the forms pictured below, when the user clicks Cancel or Sign, `Form_Popup.Visible` is set to False, allowing the code execution to continue.
  - What appears (highlighted but not selected)
    [image: What appears (highlighted but no selection)]
  - What I expect (button selected, user can hit enter or space to push button)
    [image: What I expect (button selected, user can hit enter or space to push button)]

**Things I've Tried**

- The following workarounds make the SetFocus'd control get focused:

  - Modality is programmatically turned on and off (see commented code line)

    - I would like to not need to do this
    - Interestingly, if form is saved as not modal and then modal is turned on at the line noted above, this no longer works. Weird.
  - Manual user actions:

    - Clicking the Header form section background
    - Alt-tabbing or clicking away to another app and back
- Things that don't work:

  - Setting focus multiple times
  - Setting focus to form itself (which modality should do by default)
  - Setting focus to different control types (which is my actual intent), e.g. textboxes

    - Do not appear selected and cannot immediately type text in like when focused normally
  - Tabbing interestingly shifts "focus" but never *selects* the controls which have "focus".

    - Buttons "focused" in this manner have the peripheral highlight but no "selected" indication (thin dotted line around caption).
    - Textboxes and listboxes "focused" in this manner have no indication they have been tabbed to and cannot be typed into.
  - Setting TabIndex for the desired control to 0 and both selecting nothing or that control.

**References:**

- [MSDN VBA Form.Modal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-modal-property-access)
- [MSDN VBA SetFocus method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-setfocus-method-access)

Comment: What if you set TabIndex to 0 for the cancel button and then set TabIndex accordingly higher to the other controls?

Comment: @braX Same effect.

Comment: I dont really understand what the reason is for that Sleep Loop you have in there... Does it act as you expect if you comment that out?

Comment: What happens if you set the focus in the on open or current event  of the form ? I'm not sure the code will run when called in this way on a modal form as control has passed to it not the calling form. Also A form itself cannot get focus if there are any controls on it.

Comment: It properly selects the target control when the form is opened normally, e.g. `Docmd.OpenForm "Popup_Sign"` or just opening it from the navigation window. I have a SetFocus in the Form_Load, but that doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: @braX The sleep loop keeps the code from progressing while the user is editing stuff on Form_Popup. When the user is hits either Cancel or Sign, the `Form_Popup.Visible` is set to False and the code continues.

Comment: Any calling code execution is paused until  a form that is opened modally is closed, you may simply be suffering from that?

Comment: @Minty What you are thinking is forms opened as dialogs. If I didn't have the loop, the code would go straight to the end. For instance, I was just able to add a line between `SetFocus` and the do loop that set one of the textboxes to "" and it worked.

Comment: are you sure that `CommandCancel` is the cancel button?

Comment: Yes, though that is unrelated to the issue (I've had this with and without the Cancel property set). The inability to SetFocus applies to all controls on the form. I think the issue is related to modality, not anything regarding the controls themselves.